# DevExpress SpellChecker doesn't work with ShowDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, spell-checking

I have a form with RichTextBox and I want it to have a spell checker with AsYouType feature that will underline misspelled words for different languages.

I've added SpellChecker on the form with AsYouType feature and it doesn't work if you show form with ShowDialog() method.

If I use Show() method for my form then spellchecker works but I need my form be modal.